# Creating a bounded operator from an unbounded symbol ? - discussion around the Calderon-Vaillancourt theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis, semiclassical-analysis

Calderon-Vaillancourt theorem states that any quantization of a bounded symbol (in the sense of [this article](https://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/%7Ebouclet/Notes-de-cours-exo-exam/M2/Calderon-Vaillancourt.pdf) for example) is a bounded operator on the $L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ space.

I was wondering if there was any way of going back from a $L^2(\mathbb{R^n})-$bounded pseudo-differential operator to one of its symbols. More precisely, I wondered if it is true that, for such operator $P$, there exists a bounded symbol $p$ such that $Op(p)=P$.

I've heard this is a hard task to go from operators to symbols in the general case. Beals theorem, which is a theorem proving a given operator is pseudo-differential, answers my question for some specific cases (hypothesis on commutators appear) but not in the general case.

Thus, I kind of assumed the answer to that question is : no.

So, my question here is :

**Is it possible to find a counter-example, that is to say an unbounded symbol $p$ (a smooth function that has at least one of its derivatives not in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})$) which quantization $P = Op(p)$ is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ ?**

Thanks in advance to anyone interested in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1. You can go from an operator to its symbol using the notion of *oscillatory testing* for appropriate symbol classes. See, for example, Theorem 4.19 in Zworski's text.
2. I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say a derivative of the symbol is not in $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ since symbols are defined by $\mathbb{R}^{2n}.$ Let's assume that you meant $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Then, the answer is yes. In fact, the Calderon-Vaillancourt is even stronger than the theorem stated in your link; it holds for symbols in $S^{0}_{\rho,\rho}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ provided that $\rho\in [0,1).$ So, if $p\in S^{0}_{\rho,\rho}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ and $\rho\in [0,1),$ then $Op(p)$ is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but one is only guaranteed that $$|D^\alpha_ x p(x,\xi)|\leq C_\alpha \langle\xi\rangle^{\rho|\alpha|}.$$ So, the $x$ derivatives do not need to be bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
1. I will look into that notion, thanks.
2. Yes I meant $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, my bad.